# Cannot rebuild node-gyp with exit code null

Tags: node.js, exit-code, node-gyp, rebuild, gyp

I'm trying to use `node-gyp rebuild`, but I encountered a weird issue.
I think I have followed almost every thread.

I am running the command on macOS BigSur 11.2.2, Apple Silicon.

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: null
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:376:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:284:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/.../Path
gyp ERR! node -v v15.5.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```